# Importing a python module takes too much memory

Tags: python, python-import, memory-profiling

I am working on a quite big existing Python application and I am now trying to reduce its memory usage.
Thanks to [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) I got this:

```
23   11.289 MiB    0.434 MiB    from remote import settings
24   14.422 MiB    3.133 MiB    from remote.controller import ChannelManager
25   14.422 MiB    0.000 MiB    from remote import channel as channel_module
```

As you can see at line 24 the memory usage increases of 3.13MB.
Why importing a simple class (ChannelManager) should use so much memory?
ChannelManager is not a complex class, it just wraps some logic (spawning some processes and threads).
Thank you

Comment: Without seeing what `ChannelManager` is, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: What's the package for "remote?"

Comment: I can't paste the code here.

Answer (score 4):

Unless those three megabytes are an issue, I would spend my time profiling the application itself as there's likely low-hanging fruit in your actual logic for cleanup.

When you `import` a module, Python compiles that module into bytecode (commonly seen as `.pyc` files) and stores their content into memory.  The module that you're importing (e.g. `remote.controller.ChannelManager`) is likely many lines or references an object that makes its compiled form take up that amount of space.

Your options are either to accept that as a cost of using the `ChannelManager` object or pick a smaller module in order to bring that usage down.  I would heavily suggest the former and look for portions of code that use more memory -- especially if you're on Python 2.x and there are areas that iterators could be employed.

Answer (score 1):

`from remote.controller import ChannelManager` will import the entire `remote.controller` module into memory if it has not already been imported. As such `ChannelManager` may not be the culprit at all. It could be that `remote.controller` has a whole host of dependencies that aren't loaded into memory at that point in time.

I would profile the module by itself too where the memory is being used. In all likelihood it's a one off cost, that isn't worth trying to optimise.